# NSString: isEqual vs. isEqualToString

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa, nsstring

What is the difference between `isEqual:` and `isEqualToString:`?

Why are classes adding isEqualTo* methods (isEqualToArray for NSArray, isEqualToData for NSData, ...) instead of just overriding `isEqual:` ?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

`isEqual:` compares a string to an object, and will return `NO` if the object is not a string. `isEqualToString:` is faster if you know both objects are strings, as the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/isEqualToString:) states:

> **Special Considerations**
>
> When you know both objects are strings, this method is a faster way to check equality than `isEqual:`.

`isEqualTo<Class>` is used to provide specific checks for equality. For instance; [`isEqualToArray:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/isEqualToArray:) checks that the arrays contain an equal number of objects, and that the objects at a given index return `YES` for the `isEqual:` test.

Comment: If you believe Aaron Hillegass then there is no performance difference, only a bit of type safty: http://blog.bignerdranch.com/334-isequal-vs-isequaltostring/

Comment: Thanks for the link - useful. Although you're asking us to believe Mark Dalrymple - who I do :)

Comment: Updated link: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/isequal-vs-isequaltostring/

Answer (score 17):

Also, for writing your own `-isEqual:` and `-isEqualTo<Class>:` methods, the convention is to allow nil arguments for `-isEqual:` and raise an exception for nil arguments to `-isEqualTo<Class>:`

Comment: I hadn't come across this before, any documentation that you know of?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true for isEqualToString, which just returns NO if you pass in nil.

Comment: Interesting, it's documented in the Object Comparison section of the <a href="http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW31">Cocoa Fundamentals Guide</a>

Comment: This is not true. isEqualToString does not raise an exception.

Comment: The Cocoa Fundamentals Guide web page says, "This document may not represent best practices for current development."  It's old, apparently.

Answer (score 7):

Expanding on @Abizern and @Jonathan Dann answers, both `isEqual` and `isEqualToString` work with `nil` values.

```
- (void)testStringEqual {
    NSString *string = nil;

    STAssertFalse([string isEqual:@"test"], @"NSString isEqual");
    STAssertFalse([string isEqualToString:@"test"], @"NSString isEqualToString");

    // Note that these both return NO
    STAssertFalse([string isEqual:nil], @"NSString isEqual");
    STAssertFalse([string isEqualToString:nil], @"NSString isEqualToString");

    string = @"test";

    STAssertTrue([string isEqual:@"test"], @"NSString isEqual");
    STAssertTrue([string isEqualToString:@"test"], @"NSString isEqualToString");

    STAssertFalse([string isEqual:nil], @"NSString isEqual");
    STAssertFalse([string isEqualToString:nil], @"NSString isEqualToString");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

My *guess* is that it provides a slight performance enhancement, as isEqualToString: won't have to type-check what's passed in.

Comment: Your guess is probably true:)

Answer (score 4):

I highly recommend [this](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/isequal-vs-isequaltostring/). The performance benefits of isEqualToString are basically negligible for most applications. But there are two other distinctions the author mentions:

- Type safety
- The way `nil` is handled

Comment: I don't see any difference in the way nil is handled by the two. Be nil be the receiver or argument or both.

Comment: Whatever "this" is no longer exists :/

Comment: Thanks @JaredGrubb, I found the new URL.