# using if statements with a string of letters and user input

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

Helllo I am still new to programing and had a question about using if statements while using user input with the research I have conducted i can't seem to find what I am doing wrong?
Below is my posted simple multiplication calculator.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
int a ;
int b ;
int c ;
printf("\n");
printf("\n");
printf("Welcome to calculator");
printf("\n");
printf("\n");
printf("what would you like to choose for first value?");
scanf("%d", &a);
printf("\n");
printf("What would you like to input for the second value?");
scanf("%d", &b);
c = a * b;
printf("\n");
printf("\n");
printf(" Here is your product");
printf("\n");
NSLog(@"a * b =%i", c); 

char userinput ;
char yesvari = "yes" ;
char novari = "no";

printf("\n");
printf("\n");
printf("Would you like to do another calculation?");
scanf("%i", &userinput);



if (userinput == yesvari) {
    NSLog(@" okay cool");



}

if (userinput == novari) {

    NSLog(@"okay bye");
}
```

return 0;
}

Comment: please tell us what are you expecting and then what is happening

Answer (score 2):

You are scanning the character incorrectly with `%i` and you need to compare them using `strcmp`. If you are looking for a string from the user you need to use `%s` and you need a character buffer large enough to hold the input.

Try this

```
//Make sure userinput is large enough for 3 characters  and null terminator
char userinput[4];

//%3s limits the string to 3 characters
scanf("%3s", userinput);

//Lower case the characteres
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    userinput[i] = tolower(userinput[i]);

//compare against a lower case constant yes
if(strcmp("yes", userinput) == 0)
{
    //Logic to repeat
    printf("yes!\n");
}
else
{
    //Lets just assume they meant no
    printf("bye!\n");
}
```

Comment: thanks btw and i get everything u said except for the for                      (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    userinput[i] = tolower(userinput[i]);

Comment: are you just saying that the program is just scanning for lowercase character?

Comment: `tolower()` will lower case the userinput so it wont fail if they enter "YES" or "Yes". It only works on 1 character at a time so you just need to loop over each character. Also your example is in all C, no Objective-C calls which would make what you are trying to do easier.

Comment: really okay thats great to know. I got all of the functions and the syntax from an object-C book thanks for al the help!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are reading a `char` using the wrong format `%i`:  `scanf("%i", &userinput);`

And I think it is a better to use @NSString instead of simple char (I am not even sure what will happen in ObjC if you write `char a = "asd"`, since you are giving a `char` a `char[]` value) . In that case, since strings are pointers, [you cannot use `==` to compare them](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_String_Objects_in_Objective-C#Comparing_Strings). You could use `isEqualToString` or `isEqualTo` instead. If you are interested in the difference between the two, look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292862/nsstring-isequal-vs-isequaltostring) would help.

Answer (score 0):

In C, you can't compare strings using `==`, so you would have to use a function like `strcmp()`, like this:

```
if ( !strcmp(userinput, yesvari) ) {
   //etc.
}
```

The bang (!) is used because `strcmp()` actually returns 0 when the two strings match. Welcome to the wonderful world of C!

Comment: thanks guys soo much i am literately learning from a book and stack overflow tho is a lot of help