# how to compare NSString to Variable from Push Notification Payload

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cordova

I have a Phonegap App where I recieve Push Notifications. I send a "Pagekey" in the payload, which tells the App which HTML Page to open after the App starts on a received Push Notification.

I do the following in the `- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions` (Snippets)

```
NSDictionary* extras = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
NSString *key = ((NSString*)[extras objectForKey:@"pagekey"]);//get the Pagekey
NSLog(@"key: %@", key); //prints out "2" (2 without the "")

//Load the HTML Page depending on the pagekey
self.viewController.wwwFolderName = @"www";
if([key isEqual:@"2"]){
    NSLog(@"Im in the 2 branch");
    self.viewController.startPage = @"winnings.html";
}else{
    NSLog(@"Im in the else branch");//this branch is executed(unexpected behaviour)
    self.viewController.startPage = @"index.html";
}
```

the pagekey was originally JSON Data, sent from a push notification server. Anyone knows how to compare the String properly so the correct branch is executed? thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: check class of key NSLog(@"key: %@", [key class]);

Comment: great idea. It´s an NSDecimalNumber. I try to compare it to an int now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(NSNumber *)decimalNumber` of `NSDecimalNumber`  class.

```
if ([key compare:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]]==NSOrderedSame) {
    //Equal
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `if([key isEqualToString:@"2"])...`

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292862/nsstring-isequal-vs-isequaltostring) thread for information about isEqual vs isEqualToString

Comment: oh boy Im getting a SIGABRT in a Assembly-looking file after I change it to isEqualToString...very strange.

Comment: Are you sure that `@"pagekey"` returns an `NSString` ? Maybe it's a `NSInteger` or `NSNumber`?

Comment: no, Im not sure at all. The pagekey was declared in an JSON Object.

Comment: Try this: `NSString *className = NSStringFromClass([key class]); NSLog(@"Class is %@", className);` to see what the class is of `key`.