# Compare id object and NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, compare

I cannot save the selected item from the array with a string value. Any idea what's wrong?

Its my code of compare:

```
if(self.detailItem){
    [WebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[self.detailItem description] ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
    NSString *value = (NSString *)self.detailItem;
    NSString *value1 = (NSString *)@"DecideVectorVPiramidi";
    value=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", value];
    value1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", value1];
    if (value == value1) {
        WebView.scalesPageToFit=YES;
    }
```

This is the array code:

```
case 1:
            switch (self.nomberInSection) {
                case 0:
                    self.detailViewController.detailItem =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [DecideOfZakusPath objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
                    break;
            }
break;
```

Type of `detailItem` is `id`.

For errors, I checked

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `isEqualToString`. The `==`operator will compare by reference only.

This means you have to do

```
if ( [value isEqualToString:value1] )
{
    ...
```

Your two strings will be pointers to two different memory locations, and the `==` will compare those two memory locations, and consequently evaluate to `NO`. The [`isEqualToString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html), [or `isEqual`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292862/nsstring-isequal-vs-isequaltostring), is the method to use for doing a string comparison using the string equality rules (ie. if the two strings contains the same characters, they are considered equal).

This can be a bit counter-intuitive. In Objective-C, operator overloading is not possible. In many other languages, the operators can be overloaded so that a value comparison for built in and custom classes can be done using the equality operator.