# if statement with && and || in objective c

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, logical-operators

I'm wondering what's wrong with the following, or how to fix the brackets correctly:

```
if (([newCharacter isEqual: @"ö"]||[newCharacter isEqual: @"Ö"]) && (self.currentLanguage isEqual @"Finnish/Swedish")){
//do something
}
```

the error says I should place parantheses somewhere... but I cannot figure out how. Can anyone help?

Comment: syntax error... add braces [self.currentLanguare isEqual:@""];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change this:

```
(self.currentLanguage isEqual @"Finnish/Swedish")
```

to this:

```
[self.currentLanguage isEqual:@"Finnish/Swedish"]
```

you should be ok. You need square brackets and a colon there to have a proper expression for sending the `isEqual` message, and no extra () parentheses are needed after the `&&`.

Comment: I don't think it's true that using `isEqual:` means you will only compare memory addresses. Both `isEqual:` and `isEqualToString:` should have the same results for any comparison of two string objects. @viperking's answer links to a good discussion on this. In short, I'd say that for most code it really doesn't make a meaningful difference other than style preferences.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing **`:`** after `isEqual` in this: `self.currentLanguage isEqual @"Finnish/Swedish"`

So your code should looks like:

```
if (([newCharacter isEqual: @"ö"]||[newCharacter isEqual: @"Ö"]) && (self.currentLanguage isEqual: @"Finnish/Swedish")){
   //do something
}
```

I would also recommend you a change of `isEqual:` to `isEqualToString:` as it is more obvious what are you comparing and also has some performance issues according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292862/nsstring-isequal-vs-isequaltostring)