# Verify if an NSString object's text is contained in a collection of strings (a domain)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, nsarray

Rather than a long `if` statement, what is a more compact and readable way to verify if a string is contained in a collection of possible values? In other words, check if a value is within a domain?

I want to do something like this…

```
NSArray* domain = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"dog", @"cat", @"bird", nil];
BOOL valueFoundInDomain = [domain containsObject:@"elephant"];
```

But I'm concerned about equality checking with NSString. I want to check the value of the text, not object identity.

The [documentation for NSArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) says the [`containsObject`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/containsObject%3a) method uses the `isEqual` method. But I cannot find in the [documentation for NSString](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) an explanation for its implementation of `isEqual`. The presence of the `isEqualToString` method suggests that `isEqual` may be doing something else. If that something else involves [interning of string objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning), then experimenting myself may give misleading results, so I'd like a documented answer.

Comment: See [NSString: isEqual vs. isEqualToString](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1292862/3476191)

Comment: You could do your test by building some string using `NSMutableString`. Then you can be assured that identity checks won't be involved.

Answer (score 0):

I never use `-isEqualToString:`, only `-isEqual:` and it just works as it should! (I do this for years.)

NSString is implementing `-isEqual:` and it returns `YES` if the other object is a string and it has the same contents.

In Apples Objective-C documentation, methods that are overridden from a baseclass are often not explicitely documented. But `-isEqual:` is one of the few methods that is implemented in all foundation classes where it makes sense.

Comment: FYI - Using `isEqualToString:` is more efficient if you know that both sides really are `NSString` objects. This should be considered in loops and other places where you do a lot of string comparisons.

Comment: i often just don't want the app to crash if the other object is not a string or if it is `[NSNull null]`. Calling `-isEqual:` also saves 8 bytes in the source file ;)

Comment: As I said, use `isEqualToString:` if you know both side are `NSSString`. Your `NSNull` example wouldn't apply obviously.

Comment: maybe you're right. it's just that 99% of the source code that I see has much worse performance problems than that, so that this particular issue wouldn't make a difference. Just a for-loop like `for(int i=0; i<[list count]; i++)` is inefficient compared to `int list_count = [list count]; for(int i=0; i<list_count; i++)`. Or even `if(self.foo.bar.baz.bla < 3) { self.foo.bar.baz.boo = self.foo.bar.baz.bla+2; }`. I see this kind of code so often that I just can't make myself care for the performance of `-isEqualToString:` vs. `isEqual:`.

Comment: Follow [the link in the comment](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1292862/3476191) posted on Question by NobodyNada. Turns out there is **likely *no* significant performance difference** between `isEqual` and `isEqualToString` for NSString despite the claim by Apple doc.

Answer (score 0):

The isEqual method does an additional type check to ensure you are comparing two objects of the same class.

IsEqualToString assumes you are sending a string and will crash if you send a nil or object of another type.

Your code looks good for its use case.

Answer (score 0):

Lets Try Using This

```
NSArray* domain = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"dog", @"cat", @"bird", nil];
NSIndexSet *indexes = [domain indexesOfObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent passingTest:^BOOL(NSString * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    return [obj isEqualToString:@"elephant"];
}];
// Where indexes contains matched indexes of array elements
```

Here `isqualToString:` Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether a given string is equal to the receiver using a literal Unicode-based comparison.`isEquealTo:` Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver and a given object are equal. When you know both objects are strings, `isEqualToString:` is a faster way to check equality than `isEqual:`

Comment: How does this Answer add value beyond the already existing Answers?