# Returning UIColor causing crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, theos, cydia-substrate

I'm trying to use a method to convert string to UIColor like this:

```
-(UIColor *)getColorFromString:(NSString *)color {
    if ([color isEqual: @"red"]) {
        return [UIColor redColor];
    }
    else {
        return [UIColor blackColor];
    }
}
```

Using this crashes my tweak
An example:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [self getColorFromString: @"red"]; //crashes

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; //works
```

Comment: Provide details about the crash.

Comment: %log doesn't log anything for me

Answer (score 0):

To compare two string you have to use the `isEqualToString` function.

```
-(UIColor *)getColorFromString:(NSString *)color {
    if ([color isEqualToString:@"red"]) {
        return [UIColor redColor];
    }
    else {
        return [UIColor blackColor];
    }
}
```

Comment: No, you don't. `-isEqual:` is equivalent. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292862/nsstring-isequal-vs-isequaltostring

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `@` before the string:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [self getColorFromString:@"red"];
```

Comment: That was a copy problem I made, this doesn't solve it. Sorry.